# Eclipse CDT will not create a C++ project(Eclipse throws java.lang.NullPointerException)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

I just installed CDT on Eclipse Indigo, but it can't create a project. It gives me a java.lang.NullPointerException when I double click on C++ project button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a bug, that most likely is caused by the fact that you haven't specified any source folder, check the source folder path in the first step of the new project wizard ...

Comment: It doesn't ask me to submit source folder anywhere. Where can I find that. Can you tell me the exact steps.

Comment: In the first step of the Wizard, if the wizard neither open up, then you should try reinstalling CDT ...

Comment: reinstalling worked! I always assumed downloaded files are perfect. Thanks a lot.